# Links with quotation marks are broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, editor

I'm not sure whether this is a valid (per spec) url or not, but this url

```
http://www.bestbuy.com/site/olspage.jsp?skuId=9230708&st=samsung+lcd+32"&lp=1&type=product&cp=1&id=1218063831450
```

Doesn't work in stackoverflow. It doesn't get made into a link when you view the post. Notice the quotation mark? That appears to be the problem.

Here is a [test](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/olspage.jsp?skuId=9230708&st=samsung+lcd+32"&lp=1&type=product&cp=1&id=1218063831450). This is the page it [should link to](http://tinyurl.com/qbrdjt).

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.2 - none of these character are URL safe for content description

Comment: http://www.bestbuy.com/site/olspage.jsp?skuId=9230708&st=samsung+lcd+32%22&lp=1&type=product&cp=1&id=1218063831450

Comment: So the problem is Best Buy. figures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's that double-quote (") in the URL. The parser is expecting another one because it would be used as the `TITLE` part of the link.

It's not intuitive, but you'll have to encode that double-quote as:

```
%22
```

So your above link would be like this:

> http://example.com/site/olspage.jsp?skuId=9230708&st=samsung+lcd+32%22&lp=1&type=product&cp=1&id=1218063831450

Comment: That edit was obviously just an excuse to post that certain edit summary.

Answer (score 0):

[As of recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60211/auto-escape-url-when-entering-with-hyperlink-button-ctrll/82263#82263), when entering a link via the button (or Ctrl-L), the characters will automatically be escaped.