# Rendering of Hyperlinks with Quotation Marks

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Links with quotation marks are broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21556/links-with-quotation-marks-are-broken)

I've found what appears to be a bug in the rendering of hyperlinks with quotation marks in them.

To see what I mean, have a look at the edit history of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733938/looking-for-tool-that-can-see-tables-and-data-in-sqlce-in-computer-that-isnt-h/2164886#2164886).

You'll notice that if you rollback to the original version of the answer (by actually saving it), you'll see that the markdown isn't replaced with the proper text hyperlink; it remains on the page.

The issue appears to be the quotation marks in the hyperlink, which, when removed, fixes the markdown rendering issue (don't worry, I've verified that the hyperlink still works after removing the extraneous quotation marked bits of the hyperlink, as you'll see in my edit).

Comment: So, the example is `http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx/"Query Express"` (Which, incidentally, was missing a space before the first double quote in its Markdown, to get a title on mouse hover. And, also as an aside to avoid confusion: you're referring to *an answer*, not a comment.)

Comment: Right, an answer as opposed to a comment.  Fixed. :)

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21556/links-with-quotation-marks-are-broken (summary: the double-quote isn't actually a valid URL character - URL should be written: `http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx/%22Query%20Express%22` [a decent browser will auto-encode that for you...])